# Alloy assert check

Tags: assert, alloy

I'm trying to write an assert statement to the effect that once a mark is entered for
any student then the student always has a mark for that course (although it's possible the
mark may change). I already know how to check if the student has the mark or not, but i don't know how to do it in case the student doesn't have any mark to begin with. Also, how can i write a check statement for this assert statement?

```
sig Student, Tutor, Mark {} 

sig Course { 
  reg : set Student, 
  alloc : Student -> Tutor, 
  result : Student -> Mark 
}
```

**This is what i tried**

```
assert chekmark
  {all c:Course | let c' = CO/next[c] |
     some Student.(c.Result) => some Student.(c.Result)}

check checkmark for 3
```

But somehow it says: This expression failed to be typechecked.
Am i right or wrong,and how can i fix it if i'm right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ordering on Courses is not going to be a solution for your problem. Using the ordering module simply places a total order on all courses (so CO/next[c] just returns the course immediately following c in that order), whereas you probably want to have a sequence of marks for each (Course, Student) pair.

Maybe something like this

```
sig Student, Tutor, Mark {}

sig Course {
  reg : set Student,
  alloc : Student -> Tutor,
  result : set Grade
}

sig Grade {
  student: one Student,
  marks: seq Mark
}
```

Using Alloy sequences automatically gives you the property you want, that is, if the `marks` field is non-empty, then it is going to contain a sequence of Marks so no nulls in the middle are possible.

With this model, you might want to add a fact that enforces at most one grade per student per course.

```
fact oneGradePerStudentPerCourse {
  all c: Course {
    all s: c.reg |   
      lone {g: c.result | g.student = s}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what i need is the assert/check statement. I have never used it before so it's pretty complicated for me.

Comment: If an assert/check statement is all you need, here is one:

  `assert x {Student = Student}`, `check x for 3`

Comment: well, the thing is that i need to use an assert/check statement for this problem. This is one of the problems in the practice section for assert/check.